# Any tool to load large csv files quickly on windows 7

Tags: csv

I am working with relatively large CSV files (1.5 MB+) and while testing the code, I have to frequently open up the CSV files to read a particular row, validate the data are there and then close the CSV file and move to another one.

Files which are larger than 1.5 MB are taking about 40 seconds per file open on my computer. Is there any tool that will allow me to open large CSV files quickly (I am only looking to read the CSV file and therefore a CSV reader that opens up files quickly will be useful)

Alternatively, if there is any tool that will perhaps when the first 1000 lines 
or the last 1000 lines will be good.
I know I can do this in UNIX by using commandline utilities but then they dump the data in different files and again I will have to delete those files. Moreover, I'm looking for a solution on Windows.

I hope somebody can help resolve this. Thank you for any inputs!

Answer (score 2):

`notepad++` will open a file of that size very quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have tried using notepad++. For me the time taken is shorter than Microsoft Excel but still quite long given that I just have to look at a few lines and then move onto another CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with Windows PowerShell, you may use `gc` command.

To see the first 1000 lines of a file:

```
gc -head 1000 filename.csv
```

To see the last 1000 lines of a file:

```
gc -head 1000 filename.csv
```

This is similar to the `head` and `tail` in UNIX. BTW both in Windows and UNIX those commands do not dump the data into different files and require you to delete.

You may also find the `more` command useful if you try to browse through a large file.